# Drawing a horizontal line to a specific column number in ESS

Tags: ess

I want to be able to execute a command in ESS to quickly add a horizontal line (using dashes) out to column 80.

This will be used for header comments. I'd like to be able to re-execute the command to redraw the line if I change the header comment as edits will change the end point of the line from column 80. E.g.

```
## Title here -------------------------

## Edited title here -------------------------
```

If I execute the command on the second one, it'll shorten it to the same length as the first (imagining that it ends at column 80).

Comment: check out comment-box (or is it box-comment?) for a way of doing something similar. If you don't like that, you could do exactly what you want with a few lines of elisp

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. Yes, it's comment-box. But that led me onto rebox2, which is more customizable and super functional.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tyler's comment above, I found [rebox2](https://github.com/lewang/rebox2/blob/master/rebox2.el). This enables easily adding comment boxes and changing them as you go, which is bound to `M-q`.

This doesn't do exactly as I asked, but it is very customizable and does the trick nicely for headings inside ESS. e.g.:

```
## ---------- ##    
## Title here ##
## ---------- ##
```